# Show original element after clicking outside of the secondary element

Tags: jquery

I want hide secondary image when user clicks anywhere else like somewhere in the page so if you look at the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sjvj/), black box should become red again after user clicks outside of the black box.

I got the hiding code from this source: [Use jQuery to hide a DIV when the user clicks outside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it).

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<img id="language_arrow_bottom" src="http://placehold.it/32/ff0000" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" />
<img id="language_arrow_up" src="http://placehold.it/32/000000" width="13px" height="13px" alt="" style="display:none;" />
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#language_arrow_bottom').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').hide();
        $('#language_arrow_up').show();
    });

    $('#language_arrow_up').click(function(event)
    {
        $('#language_arrow_up').hide();
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').show();
    });

    var container = $('#language_arrow_up');

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#language_arrow_bottom').click(function(event) {
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').hide();
        $('#language_arrow_up').show();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        $('#language_arrow_up').hide();
        $('#language_arrow_bottom').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5sjvj/2/

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the code on `mouseup` event on the `document`. The way you were doing it, the code used to execute when the page got loaded and used to throw an error for `undefined` variable `e`.

All I did was put the same code you had inside `$(document).mouseup(function (e) { ... }` and it worked. Now, whenever you click mouse and leave it i.e. the mouse button comes up, this method will be called.

```
 $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
        var container = $('#language_arrow_up');

        if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            container.hide();
            $('#language_arrow_bottom').show();
        }
    });
```

See working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/5sjvj/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the click on something that's above the two elements you're toggling, otherwise you won't catch it.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        console.log(e.target);

        if(e.target === $("#language_arrow_bottom")[0]) {
            $("#language_arrow_up").show();
            $("#language_arrow_bottom").hide();
        } else if(e.target !== $("#language_arrow_up")[0]) {
            $("#language_arrow_up").hide();
            $("#language_arrow_bottom").show();
        }
    });
});
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5sjvj/1/).

Answer (score 0):

another way!

html:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

css:

```
.arrow {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/32/ff0000');
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
}
.arrow.down {
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/32/000000');
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $arrow = $('.arrow');

    $arrow.on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        $arrow.toggleClass('down');

        if ($arrow.hasClass('down')) {
            //down
        } else {
            //up
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', function () {
        $arrow.removeClass('down');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5sjvj/8/